# Jmeter is skipping a while loop in a transaction, and I don't know why

Tags: testing, while-loop, jmeter, performance-testing

I made a jmeter script for a perf test that have two step in a transaction:
the first step post some info in the server
the next step has a while loop to request the info and if the server doesn't write it, try it again (basically a while with expected answer and a count) and it works fine for a few samples.
The problem is that after some samples, the while step si simply skipped.
I try the best to check if there is a problem with the variables being shared in the threads (I renew the data of the expeted answer and make the counter with the var "${__counter(TRUE,)}").
But nevertheless the script after a time simply ignore the while step.

For more info:
The while loop is made with the logic controller "while controller".
Jmeter version is 5.1

Somebody had the same problem before? can anyone have a posible solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

While Controller's children are executed until the [function or variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you're using as the condition is evaluated to `true`

It can be skipped in situation like below:

1. You have variable `foo` with the value of `true`
2. While Controller loops until `foo` variable becomes `false`
3. If there is another iteration on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level the variable is still `false` hence the thread (virtual user) doesn't enter the While Controller

So I would recommend checking each part of your While Controller's condition using i.e. [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) and if my assumption is correct just reset the variable holding the value with i.e. [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or [Set Variables Action Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SetVariablesAction/) just before the While Controller.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I just put a debug sampler previous the while loop and checked with another sampler that runs the while. It seems that if the thread repeat itself (for the iteration) thats why it doesn't run the while. Like, if the virtual user run two times but the data is different, then it doesn't enter the loop. 
I don't know how to force the thread to enter the loop, you say that if I put a new variable indeed it has to enter, but this is not the case (the variables are different, but the thread is the same)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.
First the while condition passed only as a counter.
Then I put a sampler for the counter and another sampler inside the while that has an if that if the data in the request is what I look, then add to the counter the size to go out.
For some reason, the variables used for check the request (a regex extractor and a xpathextractor) don't restart after every iteration and after a few samples, for some reason the while was always skipped.
The first while (the bad one) was this:

```
${__jexl3("${var}" != "${VAR2}" && "${__counter(TRUE,)}" < 8)}
```

For some reason, after a few iterations the first condition come always true.

The solution:
sampler before while:

```
vars.put("counter","1");
```

while condition:

```
${__jexl3("${counter}" <= 8)}
```

sampler in while:

```
if ("${var}" != "${VAR2}"){
int counter= Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counter")) +1;
vars.put("counter",Integer.toString(counter));
}else vars.put("counter","10");
```